# Find probabilities of an exponential random variable, X, with parameter $\lambda >0 $

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda > 0$. Find the probabilities $$P(X>2/\lambda)$$ and $$P(|X-1/\lambda|<2/\lambda)$$

I am not sure where to start with this. I know that $P(X>x)=1-F(x)=e^{-\lambda x}$. Does this help with the first one in some way? Do I plug $2/\lambda$ in for $x$ and that gets rid of the $\lambda$'s so the answer would be ${e^-}^2$? Lost on the second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the fact that you know that 
$$\Pr(X\gt x)=e^{-\lambda x}$$
(if $x\ge 0$) is very useful.  Equivalently,
$$F(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$$
**when** $x\ge 0$,  and $F(x)=0$ elsewhere. Being aware of the "elsewhere" part can help avoid error.

For the first problem, just substitute $2/\lambda$ for $x$. Note that $\lambda(2/\lambda)=2$.

For the second, let's "unwrap" what $|X-1/\lambda|\lt 2/\lambda$ says. It says that $X$ is not too far from $1/\lambda$, indeed within $2/\lambda$ of $1/\lambda$. More precisely, it says that 
$$\cfrac{1}{\lambda}-\cfrac{2}{\lambda} \lt X \lt \cfrac{1}{\lambda}+\cfrac{2}{\lambda}.$$
Some simplification reduces this to
$$-\cfrac{1}{\lambda}\lt X\lt \cfrac{3}{\lambda}.$$
But note that an exponentially distributed random variable can never be negative. 
So all we want is
$$\Pr\left(X\lt \cfrac{3}{\lambda}\right).$$
Another way of arriving at the answer is to note that our probability is $F(3/\lambda)-F(-1/\lambda)$. But now we must be careful. Since $-1/\lambda$ is negative, $F(-1/\lambda)=0$, so our answer is just $F(3/\lambda)$. We get this by substituting $3/\lambda$ for $x$ in the formula for $F(x)$.